# WEXITSTATUS(childStatus) returns 0 but waitpid returns -1

Tags: c, linux, waitpid, wexitstatus

As far as I know if waitpid returns -1 then it is error condition. How it possible to get success (EXIT_SUCCUSS) from child process in WEXITSTATUS(childStatus)?

What is the difference between childStatus in waitpid & return value from WEXITSTATUS(childStatus)? Does it same?

```
pid_t returnValue = waitpid(Checksum_pid, &childStatus, WNOHANG);
printf("return value = %d", returnValue);
printf("return value = %d", childStatus);

if (WIFEXITED(childStatus))
        {
            printf("Exit Code: _ WEXITSTATUS(childStatus)") ;    
            //Proceed with other calculation.  
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using the option `WNOHANG`, I would *expect* that *most* of the time `waitpid` will return `-1`, with `errno` set to `ECHILD`.

In any case, whenever `waitpid` *does* return `-1`, you shouldn't be looking at `childStatus`, which (for all I know) could be just garbage. Instead, look at `errno`, and handle it appropriately.

Otherwise, your code seems to be ok, as far as it goes, and you should be able to extract a `0` or `EXIT_SUCCESS` from `childStatus`.

The man page for `waitpid` suggests the following sample code:

```
   if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
       printf("exited, status=%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
   } else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
       printf("killed by signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
   } else if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
       printf("stopped by signal %d\n", WSTOPSIG(status));
   } else if (WIFCONTINUED(status)) {
       printf("continued\n");
   }
```

although it might be a good idea to add a final `else printf("oops?\n")` statement to this.

Comment: Is it okay to do waitpid after regular interval to make it succuss? I am getting -1 always...

Comment: I tried above mentioned as you suggested. I am getting -1 return value from waitpid all the time with errorno as ECHILD. but WIFEXITED(status) is returning 1 and WEXITSTATUS(status) returns 0. Can you please suggest me how can proceed in this condition?

Comment: @kapilddit: What happens if you replace `WNOHANG` with `0`?

Comment: I tried with 0 (instead of WNOHANG) but still problem is same. waitpid returns -1 with error ECHILD. I executed the same code in ubuntu it is giving child pid as return value from waitpid and Exit code as 0. I don't know why I am getting different behavior with same piece of code.

Comment: @kapilddit: One further suggestion: the man page says "if `SIGCHLD` is set to `SIG_IGN` ... then ... a call to `waitpid()` ... will  block until all children have terminated, and then fail with `errno` set to `ECHILD`".

Comment: I initialize the child status with 0xFFFF & now I am getting print as"continued". What does it mean?

Comment: @kapilddit: To repeat, "whenever `waitpid` does return `-1`, you shouldn't be looking at `childStatus`, which (for all I know) could be just garbage"

Answer (score 2):

WIFEXITED will read whatever value is stored in childStatus, which is just an integer, so it doesn't have to come from waitpid() - try eg

```
for(i = 0; i < 1234; i++)
        printf("WIFEXITED(%d) %s\n", i, WIFEXITED(i) ? "yes" : "no");
```

The difference between childSTatus and WIFEXITED(childStatus) is a bit tricky...
Basically the exit status has been abused to tell the exit status **or** the signal that killed the process: you'd want something like

```
struct exitstatus {
        int status;
        int signalnumber;
        enum { exited, signaled };
};
```

but those informations have been squeezed into a single integer in some way (I'm not sure if the exact details are defined anywhere): eg on my computer the low 8 bits are used for the signal number (if any) and the bits 8-15 are used for the exit code.
The important point anywhere is that you don't need to know how it happens, only how to get the results you want via WIFEXITED & friends.

Comment: In what case I will get -1 return value from waitpid? I am getting ECHILD as errono / error code. In waitpid do I need to pass the childpid for which I want to know the status? Only in parent process only I can request the status of child or in other process also I can request the status of the particular pid?

Comment: The reference for waitpid is at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html; waitpid can do both things, ie wait for any process/a specific process; yes, only in the parent process (unless you count reparenting)